# Get the category of a post by permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a post that is listed in two categories (category A, category B). When I access the post, for example "/category-b/post-name", what is the best way to get the current category of the page? In this case, I would like to receive "category-b".

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parse_url` to get the path from the URL and then use `explode` to split it into its segments:

```
$uri_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri_segments = explode('/', $uri_path);

echo $uri_segments[1]; // for www.example.com/category-b/post-name you will get 'category-b'.
```